# Buyers Premium Excel Calculation

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I have this deadline in the next few hours and I would really appreciate your help.

I need to create a formula to calculate buyer premium fees from the hammer price at an auction.

It works like this.

The hammer price is = X

- Tax1 £0-£100,000 = 25% (Every sale is charged 25% up to the value of £100,000 so max is £125,000 for this part)
- Tax2 £100,000-£2,000,000 = 20% If the hammer price exceeds £100,000, then 20% is added for this portion.
- Tax3 £2,000,000+ = 12%. If the hammer price exceeds £2,000,000, then 12% is added to this portion.

Could anyone help me create a formula that would allow me to enter the hammer price and it would auto-calculate the total fees and give me the total price including those 3 taxes.

The code I have so far is this:

```
Tax 1 = IF(B3<=100000,B3*0.25,100000*1.25) 
Tax 2 = IF(B3<1900000,B3*0.2,1900000*0.2) 
Tax 3 = (B3-2000000)*0.12
```

Comment: You might want to show the code you have so far. Now I read your 'question' as a pay-to-fix-your-problem. Bottomline, your question needs improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jasper. 
Yes I have the problem and yes I am willing to pay to have the problem fixed.

The code I have so far is this:

Tax 1    =IF(B3<=100000,B3*0.25,100000*1.25)

Tax 2    =IF(B3<1900000,B3*0.2,1900000*0.2)

Tax 2    =(B3-2000000)*0.12

I know this formula isn't correct.

Here is the exact text I'm trying to create the formula for

25.0% Up to £100,000

20.0% £100,001 to £2,000,000

12.0% £2,000,001 and above

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Darren

Comment: I don't know what to do, I can't seem to edit this text to be more clear. I'm sorry Jasper. I'm not techie at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if below calculation for hammer price £500,000 are correct.
[image]

See below screenshot for functions used:

[image: functions used]

I'm still trying to share excel file with you. Can't upload here!!!

Excel file with required functions. See instructions to change Hammer Price in file.

[Hammer Price Excel File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_B0gPNfU14BZW96SkIzSURINnc&authuser=0)

Comment: @darren-starr I have attached scrren-shot for calculations in Answer.

Comment: If you can't upload (although you can upload elsewhere and share the link), you could post the formula here though.

Comment: Most of the file upload sites don't work from office. About posting formula - I have already shared screen-shot.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I'm having difficulty formatting what you've done to fit this style worksheet. Thanks for everything you are doing to help https://plus.google.com/photos/107526643771881217224/albums/6146469461202013697/6146469462950624114?pid=6146469462950624114&oid=107526643771881217224

Comment: Darren I will share link to excel file in next 2 hours from home.

Comment: Darren : I have uploaded file to Google drive and shared link in Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple if statement for the same

Please refer to the formula in the address bar below.
[image]

Comment: Thank You.
I need something like this:
!https://plus.google.com/photos/107526643771881217224/albums/6146469461202013697/6146469462950624114?pid=6146469462950624114&oid=107526643771881217224

Comment: I like how you call this simple. That formula makes me see double! lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one which conforms to your conditions:

```
=IF(B3<=100000,B3*0.25,IF(AND(B3>100000,B3<=2000000),B3*0.2,IF(B3>2000000,B3*0.12,"NOT FOUND")))
```

Comment: you have made a mistake when copying the formula, either you have added a closing paranthesis earlier or left a comma somewhere. copy paste again.

Comment: Hey AHC, I have tried many times, copy pasting exactly. I still got the same problem

Comment: @DarrenStarr I updated the decimal delimiter in the formula. Yours is using a dot but mine is using a comma because of the local settings. Anyway, it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this down into smaller chunks

- Cost less than 100k, 25%, otherwise 25% of 100k
  `=IF(A1<10000,A1*0.25,25000)`
- Cost over 100k but less than 2m, 20% of the portion between 100k and 2m + the 25% of 100k
  `+IF(AND(A1<2000000,A1>=100000),(A1-100000)*0.2,(IF(A1<100000,0,40000)))`
- Cost over 2m, 12% of the portion over 2m plus the previous chunks`+IF(A1>2000000,(A1-2000000)*0.12,(IF(A1<2000000,0,65000)))`

Putting it all together

`=IF(A1<10000,A1*0.25,25000)+IF(AND(A1<2000000,A1>=100000),(A1-100000)*0.2,(IF(A1<100000,0,40000)))+IF(A1>2000000,(A1-2000000)*0.12,(IF(A1<2000000,0,65000)))`

Few test cases
    * Hammer Commission
    * 0 0
    * 10 2.5
    * 100000 25000
    * 100001 25000.2
    * 2000000 130000

Comment: Thanks SJB, this is the closest to what I need so far. I am testing it, but the number seems to not come out correctly.
Maybe I didn't explain clearly.
Everything gets charged 25% up to the value of £100,000 so the max at level 1 is £125,0000. Then anything above £100000 then gets taxed at the second rate 20% also, and then anything above £2000000 gets taxed at the 3rd rate 12% also.
Thanks for your help so far. I hope you can help me get this sorted